# Swagger code generation java, XML attributes

Tags: java, xml, swagger, code-generation, swagger-codegen

I'm fairly new to swagger and struggling for a while now.

I'm using the maven swagger codegen plugin (groupId: io.swagger.codegen.v3, artifactId: swagger-codegen-maven-plugin, version: 3.0.0):

```
<language>java</language>
<library>jersey1</library>
<java8>true</java8>
<withXml>true</withXml>
<configOptions>
    <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
</configOptions>
```

I have a OpenAPI definition (which I assume is 3.0) with paths to access both json and xml APIs (a couple is only json, some are both although I'm putting my efforts on XML if both are available -- reason for that were field names like `"@XX_YY"` which I couldn't get to work with reasonable effort).

This is the segment under /definitions

```
"UserExport": {
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "users": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "xml": {
          "name": "USER"
        },
        "$ref": "#/definitions/User"
      },
      "xml":{
        "name": "USER"
      }
    }
  },
  "xml": {
    "name": "USERS"
  }
}
```

Corresponding XML segment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<USERS>
  <USER ....
```

The generated model `UserExport` contains the reference to the user-list like this:

```
@JsonProperty("users")
@XmlElement(name="null")
private List<User> users = null;
```

Unmarshalling (i.e. reading an `UserObject` pojo from the service) does not work with this. If I change `name="null"` to `name="USER"` it looks good.

My questions now are:

- Is this a valid OpenAPI spec regarding the XML snipped I showed?
- If not, what would be a valid definition for this? Use the reference in the `type` attribute?
- If it is valid (which I tend to believe), how could I make it work? I'm open to use other libraries.

I have the toolchain for the code-generation running in a debugger and I'm open to modify the swagger-codegen-generators project as well.

Thanks for the help, Frank

Comment: The OpenAPI definition does not look correct. Is your response XML-only, or can it be both XML and JSON?

Comment: The API allows both XML and JSON response. The JSON looks worse and the XML looks a bit more feasible.

With my limited knowledge of OpenAPI it looks not to bad: a response containing one element (USERS) with array members (USER).